# gui not responding during process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have sql query. My push button connects with sql - it takes long time. During it, my GUI is not responding - is it possible to make it responds?

`QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` doesnt work.

### QApp.py

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
import qdarkstyle
import pyodbc

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_frame()
        self.center() #center frame
        self.layout_init() #widgets layout

    def main_frame(self):
        ### actions on meenubar
        exitAct = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.statusBar()

        moreinfo = QtWidgets.QAction('&Help',self)
        moreinfo.setStatusTip('More information')
        moreinfo.triggered.connect(self.information)
        self.statusBar()

        ### menubar
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Help')
        fileMenu.addAction(moreinfo)


        ### basic geometry and color
        self.setWindowTitle('Villain')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('dc1.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet((qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()))


    def layout_init(self):
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        ### widgets
        self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["FileNameTransformed", "OrderItemCode", "Imported", "Row"])
        self.tablewidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.tablewidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tablewidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tablewidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        #self.tablewidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.textbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textbox.setPlaceholderText('IMEI')
        self.textbox.setEnabled(True)
        regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^(0\d+|[1-9][0-9]+)$') #IMEI = only int
        self.textbox.setValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp))

        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Run process"))
        self.pb.setDisabled(True)
        self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.disableButton)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_pb)


        self.clearbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Clear all"))
        self.clearbutton.setDisabled(True)
        self.clearbutton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_clear)

        ### make vidgets alive
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.grid)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textbox)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.tablewidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pb)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.clearbutton)


    ### center main window
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())



    def information(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self,'Information','Version: 1.19.11.18\n'\
                                                             'This is the prototype of the application\n\n'\
                                                             'Please, contact karol.chojnowski@digitalcaregroup.com for comments and suggestions\n\n'\
                                          'Digital Care - Data Processing Team')

    def disableButton(self):
        if len(self.textbox.text())> 0:
            self.pb.setDisabled(False)
            self.clearbutton.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            self.pb.setDisabled(True)
            self.clearbutton.setDisabled(True)


    ### run process button
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_pb(self):
        if len(self.textbox.text()) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            self.sql_query()


    ### clear all
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_clear(self):
        if len(self.textbox.text())> 0:
            self.textbox.clear()
            self.tablewidget.setRowCount(0)
            self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(3, 200)

    def setCredentials(self, credentials):
        self._credentials = credentials

    def sql_query(self):
        ser = "10.96.6.14"
        base = "PROD_WAREX2"
        username, pwd = self._credentials

        QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        try:
            self.connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=ser, database=base,
                         user=username, password=pwd)
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.res = cursor.execute(""" SELECT FI.FileNameTransformed,
                FI.OrderItemCode,
                FIR.Imported,
                FR.Row
                FROM [FileRows] AS FR
                JOIN [FileImportRows] AS FIR ON FR.RowId = FIR.RowId
                JOIN [FileImports] AS FI ON FIR.FileImportId = FI.Id 
                WHERE FR.Row LIKE ? """, ('%' + self.textbox.text() + '%'))
            if not cursor.rowcount:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'IMEI', "No items found")
                cursor.close()
                pass
            else:
                self.tablewidget.setRowCount(0)
                for row, form in enumerate(self.res):
                    self.tablewidget.insertRow(row)
                    for column, item in enumerate(form):
                        newitem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
                        self.tablewidget.setItem(row, column, newitem)
                cursor.close()
                self.table_performance()
                self.tablewidget.sortItems(0, order=QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)
        except:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', "Something went wrong\n\n"\
                                          "Contact karol.chojnowski@digitalcaregroup.com")
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.setStyleSheet((qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()))


    def table_performance(self):
        self.tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(3, 2500)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
```

main .py:

### Villain.py

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from QLogin import LoginDialog
from QApp import MainWindow
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

login = LoginDialog()
login.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(resource_path('dc1.png')))

if login.exec_() != QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
    sys.exit(-1)

window = MainWindow()
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(resource_path('dc1.png')))
window.setGeometry(500, 150, 800, 500)
window.setCredentials(login.credentials()) # <----
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `processEvents()` implies in most cases a bad design. If you have a heavy task, do not execute it in the main thread, execute it in another thread and send the necessary data to the main thread by means of signals or with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` (this last option will be used since it is not necessary so much connection).

On the other hand you should only add the stylesheet once, if there are new widgets they will take as a basis the stylesheet.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
import qdarkstyle
import pyodbc

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_frame()
        self.center() #center frame
        self.layout_init() #widgets layout

    def main_frame(self):
        ### actions on meenubar
        exitAct = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self, shortcut='Ctrl+Q', statusTip='application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(self.close)

        moreinfo = QtWidgets.QAction('&Help',self, statusTip='More information')
        moreinfo.triggered.connect(self.information)

        ### menubar
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Help')
        fileMenu.addAction(moreinfo)

        ### basic geometry and color
        self.setWindowTitle('Villain')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('dc1.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet((qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()))

    def layout_init(self):
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        ### widgets
        self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["FileNameTransformed", "OrderItemCode", "Imported", "Row"])
        self.tablewidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.tablewidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tablewidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tablewidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        #self.tablewidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.textbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textbox.setPlaceholderText('IMEI')
        self.textbox.setEnabled(True)
        regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^(0\d+|[1-9][0-9]+)$') #IMEI = only int
        self.textbox.setValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp))

        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Run process"))
        self.pb.setDisabled(True)
        self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.disableButton)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_pb)

        self.clearbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Clear all"))
        self.clearbutton.setDisabled(True)
        self.clearbutton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_clear)

        ### make vidgets alive
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid.addWidget(self.textbox)
        grid.addWidget(self.tablewidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.pb)
        grid.addWidget(self.clearbutton)

        self.table_performance()

    ### center main window
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def information(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self,'Information','Version: 1.19.11.18\n'\
                                                             'This is the prototype of the application\n\n'\
                                                             'Please, contact karol.chojnowski@digitalcaregroup.com for comments and suggestions\n\n'\
                                          'Digital Care - Data Processing Team')


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def disableButton(self):
        val = bool(self.textbox.text())
        self.pb.setDisabled(not val)
        self.clearbutton.setDisabled(not val)

    ### run process button
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_pb(self):
        if self.textbox.text():
            threading.Thread(target=self.sql_query, daemon=True).start()
    ### clear all
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked_clear(self):
        if self.textbox.text():
            self.textbox.clear()
            self.tablewidget.setRowCount(0)
            self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(3, 200)

    def setCredentials(self, credentials):
        self._credentials = credentials

    def table_performance(self):
        self.tablewidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tablewidget.setColumnWidth(3, 2500)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def show_warning(self, title, msg):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, title, msg)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def clear_items(self):
        self.tablewidget.setRowCount(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int, str)
    def add_item(self, row, column, val):
        if row >= self.tablewidget.rowCount():
            self.tablewidget.insertRow(self.tablewidget.rowCount())
        newitem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(val)
        self.tablewidget.setItem(row, column, newitem)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def sort_items(self):
        self.tablewidget.sortItems(0, order=QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)

    def sql_query(self):
        ser = "10.96.6.14"
        base = "PROD_WAREX2"
        username, pwd = self._credentials
        try:
            connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=ser, database=base,
                         user=username, password=pwd)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            res = cursor.execute(""" SELECT FI.FileNameTransformed,
                FI.OrderItemCode,
                FIR.Imported,
                FR.Row
                FROM [FileRows] AS FR
                JOIN [FileImportRows] AS FIR ON FR.RowId = FIR.RowId
                JOIN [FileImports] AS FI ON FIR.FileImportId = FI.Id 
                WHERE FR.Row LIKE ? """, ('%' + self.textbox.text() + '%'))
            if not cursor.rowcount:
                QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "show_warning", 
                    QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, 
                    QtCore.Q_ARG(str, 'IMEI'), QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "No items found"))
            else:
                QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "clear_items", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
                for row, form in enumerate(res):
                    for column, item in enumerate(form):
                        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "add_item", 
                            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                            QtCore.Q_ARG(int, row), QtCore.Q_ARG(int, column), QtCore.Q_ARG(str, str(item)))
                        QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
                QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "sort_items", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
            cursor.close()
        except:
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "show_warning", 
                    QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, 
                    QtCore.Q_ARG(str, 'Error'), QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "Something went wrong\n\n"\
                                          "Contact karol.chojnowski@digitalcaregroup.com"))
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like it doesnt work completly. Threading works, but when i call `sql_query` method it works, then it closes program with pycharm info `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`
It seems that the problem is with writing to the table?
During my main thread, clicking anything, it stops working sql_query?

Comment: I found and corrected it:`self.tablewidget.insertRow(self.tablewidget.rowCount())`
But got only first column, the rest is empty.
Errors: `QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread`

Comment: Oh, i was too fast: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method MainWindow::show_warning(QString,QString)
Candidates are:
    show_warning(int)
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method MainWindow::show_warning(QString,QString)
Candidates are:
    show_warning(int)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kchojnowski\Documents\Python_projects\GUI Natalia\QApp.py", line 187, in sql_query
    QtCore.Q_ARG(str, 'IMEI'), QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "No items found"))
RuntimeError: QMetaObject.invokeMethod() call failed`

Comment: @Karol357 Have you used my last code ?, I already correct those errors.